# $this when not in object's context

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\classes\pagination.php on line 20

My workflow is the following:

From pagination2.php page i initialized all the class instances:

```
  require_once '../core/init.php';


  $pagination=new Pagination();
  $user=new User();
  $data=$user->data();

  $pagenum=$pagination::getAllContent('userpost',$data->user_id);
  echo $pagenum;
```

pagination.php page contains pagination class

```
class Pagination{
    private $_db;
    public function __construct(){
       $this->_db=DB::getInstance();
       print_r($this->_db);
    }

    public static function getUserContentOffset($table,$offset,$id){
        $val=array();
        $val[]=$id;
        $pointerDB=$this->_db->fetchPostByOffset($table,$offset,$val);
        return $pointerDB->results();
    }
    public static function getAllContent($table,$id){
        $val=array();
        $val[]=$id;
        print_r($val);
        $pointerDB=$this->_db->fetchAllPost($table,$val); // error is here
        return $pointerDB->countit();

    }



    }
```

`$this->_db` should bear the instance of `DB class`.Then why i am getting the error when i call a method of DB class using `$this->_db`

DB.php

```
class DB{

        private static $_instance=null;
    private $_pdo,$_query,$_error=false,$_results,$_count=0;
    public function __construct(){
        try{
           $this->_pdo=new PDO('mysql:host='.Config::get('mysql/host').';dbname='.Config::get('mysql/db'),Config::get('mysql/username'),Config::get('mysql/password'));

        }catch(PDOException $e){
           die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static function getInstance(){

       if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
          self::$_instance=new DB();
       }
       return self::$_instance;
    }

   public function fetchAllPost($table,$val=array()){
            $sql="SELECT title FROM ".$table." WHERE users_user_id = ?";
            return $this->query($sql,$val);
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating an `instance` for calling `static` function. You can call `Pagination` static function via `Pagination::getAllContent('userpost',$data->user_id);`

Comment: just in case if i decide to put any public function inside pagination class.It is not completed yet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this` is not available in static methods. Static Methods don't have any Object associated with them, hence there is no `$this` reference available inside a static method. So you can declare a static `properties` and use it in your `static` function. Now your calling `DB` instance should be on static `property` so that you can access it in your static functions.

```
class Pagination{
     private static $_db;
     public function __construct(){
        self::$_db = DB::getInstance();
     }

    public static function getUserContentOffset($table,$offset,$id){
       $val=array();
       $val[]=$id;
       $pointerDB=self::$_db->fetchPostByOffset($table,$offset,$val);
       return $pointerDB->results();
    }
    public static function getAllContent($table,$id){
      $val=array();
      $val[]=$id;
      $pointerDB = self::$_db->fetchAllPost($table,$val); // error is here
      return $pointerDB->countit();
   }
}
```

Now you can try it this way

```
$pagintation = new Pagination();
$pagenum = $pagination->getAllContent('userpost',$data->user_id);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score -1):

You are using `static` functions which don't have an instance to reference to.
Trying using `self::` instead.

```
self::$_db
```

Comment: can't understand !  fetchAllPost() is not a static function.so why should i use it ?

Comment: No, but you are calling it *within* a static function.

Comment: tried it not working :( $this->_db has the DB class instance .i have tested it in the pagination.php class using print_r($this->_db);

Comment: So you changed `$pointerDB=$this->_db->fetchAllPost($table,$val);` to `$pointerDB=self::$_db->fetchAllPost($table,$val);` and you got the same error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99278/discussion-between-al-zami-and-lock).